# Magento 2.3.3 Icons not showing correctly

Tags: magento2.3.3, luma-theme, icons-blank-theme

Fresh install of 2.3.3 with Luma theme sample data. The icon in the navigation bar and the search bar aren't showing correctly. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to hit below commands

```
sudo rm -rf var/* generated/* pub/static/frontend/*
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't help.